# Sorted-ception - Adding to a SortedList inside a SortedDictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

So this is a thing I've been looking at for quite some time now. And I can't see where I did it wrong. Hope you guys can help ^^

So my problem is that I have 311 objects which I try to sort into a `SortedDictionary<int, SortedList<int, Entry>>` *(>)*. However the result is a dictionary with only 112 objects. Where do the rest go and why ain't they going where the should?

```
    public SortedDictionary<int, SortedList<int, Entry>> GetSortedByForum(int id)
    {
        SortedDictionary<int, SortedList<int, Entry>> result = new SortedDictionary<int, SortedList<int, Entry>>();

        foreach (var e in GetByForum(id))
        {
            e.fk_entry = e.fk_entry == null
                ? 0
                : e.fk_entry;

            if (!result.ContainsKey((int)e.fk_entry))
                result[(int)e.fk_entry] = new SortedList<int, Entry>();

            if (!result[(int)e.fk_entry].ContainsKey(e.fk_language))
                result[(int)e.fk_entry][e.fk_language] = new Entry();

            result[(int)e.fk_entry][e.fk_language] = e;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Background info might help:

- **fk_entry** is the objects parent. An `entry` can only have on parent, but can however have multiple children.
- **fk_language** is the language of the entry, a entry can have several translations
- **entry** is an article of some sort. The dictionary should order them by parent, and then by language.

Comment: are you saying that GetForum returns 311 etries but result only has 112. If so then GetForum is returning many duplicates

Comment: @pm100: That's what I'm saying. However there are no duplicates. Already checked that ^^

Comment: so - find one of the disappeared entries and follow what happens to it - put a conditional break point in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the following line of code. It only adds the first entry for a particular language - later entries for the same parent and language are not added.

```
if (!result[(int)e.fk_entry].ContainsKey(e.fk_language))
    result[(int)e.fk_entry][e.fk_language] = new Entry();
```

Keeping as much of your code the same as possible, I think you want a *collection* of entries associated with each particular language:

```
var result = new SortedDictionary<int, SortedList<int, List<Entry>>>();

...
...

if (!result[(int)e.fk_entry].ContainsKey(e.fk_language))
    result[(int)e.fk_entry][e.fk_language] = new List<Entry>();

result[(int)e.fk_entry][e.fk_language].Add(e);
```

Given your comment, *"How would I do it if I wanted to also sort the different translations by fk_language?"*, you could try incorporating something like this into your loop:

```
var result2 = new SortedDictionary<int, Dictionary<int, List<int>>>();

if (!result2[(int)e.fk_entry].ContainsKey(e.some_unique_entry_id))
    result2[(int)e.fk_entry][e.some_unique_entry_id] = new List<int>();

result2[(int)e.fk_entry][e.some_unique_entry_id].Add(e.fk_language);
```

Or use LINQ to query the first SortedDictionary, to manipulate it into the format you need.

Comment: That's it!

A bonus question: How would I do it if I wanted to also sort the different translations by `fk_language`?